# How to create a bot that automatically responds to comments and sends messages to customers on your Facebook page

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-chatbot

I want to develop a chatbot that can trigger when a user comments on a post on the page, then it will automatically reply and send a message to that user.

I'm referencing the following facebook documentation but it doesn't seem right
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference/pages_read_user_content

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/private-replies

Comment: Is it necessary to change the application to live mode to receive live data? Mr @CBroe

Comment: It should work for users that have a role in the app before that.